# How can I ignore parent padding and create full width table header in HTML?

Tags: html, css

I want to ignore .container's padding and make table header (row with #/First Name/...) full-width, but without moving text content (I mean only background of table header should be full width). How can I do this? Thanks.

```css
body {
  background: #eee;
}

.container {
  width: 350px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: #ddd;
  padding: 20px;
  margin-top: 30px;
}

table {
  width: 100%;
}

table thead tr {
  background: #555;
  color: #fff;
}

table thead tr td {
  padding-right: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <h3 style="margin:0">Hello!</h3>
    <br />
    <table cellspacing=0>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <td>#</td>
        <td>First Name</td>
        <td>Last Name</td>
        <td>Phone</td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Test</td>
        <td>+1 234 56-7888</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Test</td>
        <td>+1 234 56-7888</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

**UPD**: Here is what exactly I am trying to get: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WZh9o.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could minus `margin-left` the table and give it a fixed `width`. After this you just add a `padding` to left and right for the first and last `td`

```css
body {
  background: #eee;
}
.container {
  background: #ddd none repeat scroll 0 0;
  margin: 30px auto 0;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 350px;
}
table {
    margin-left: -20px;
    width: 390px;
}
table thead tr {
  background: #555;
  color: #fff;
}
table thead tr td {
  padding-right: 15px;
}

td:first-child {
    padding-left: 20px;
}

td:last-child {
    padding-right: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h3 style="margin:0">Hello!</h3>
  <br />
  <table cellspacing=0>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <td>#</td>
        <td>First Name</td>
        <td>Last Name</td>
        <td>Phone</td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Test</td>
        <td>+1 234 56-7888</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Test</td>
        <td>+1 234 56-7888</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

---

**EDIT:** Here's a snippet for a responsive table. I changed the css from the `.container`. It's padding will not apply on the table anymore.

```css
body {
  background: #eee;
}
.container {
  background: #ddd none repeat scroll 0 0;
  margin: 30px auto 0;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  width: 350px;
}
.container > * {
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
}
.container > table {
  padding-left: 0;
  padding-right: 0;
}
table {
  width: 100%;
}
table thead tr {
  background: #555;
  color: #fff;
}
table thead tr td {
  padding-right: 15px;
}
td:first-child {
  padding-left: 20px;
}
td:last-child {
  padding-right: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
      <h3 style="margin:0">Hello!</h3>
      <br />
      <table cellspacing=0>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <td>#</td>
            <td>First Name</td>
            <td>Last Name</td>
            <td>Phone</td>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>John</td>
            <td>Test</td>
            <td>+1 234 56-7888</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>John</td>
            <td>Test</td>
            <td>+1 234 56-7888</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
```

Comment: Sorry, but absolute positioning is not an option, because the table can be dynamic and there is no way to recalculate its height.

Comment: @Alex I updated the css. How about this? Now without a fixed height and absolute positioning.

Comment: Thanks. But what should I do if the width of the container is not fixed (responsive layout)?

Comment: @Alex I added a new snippet. It's responsive now.

Answer (score 3):

Simply provide a margin:-20px and increase the width of the table.

Answer (score 0):

Just make your `container` class padding to `padding: 20px 0;` and and width to `width:100%;`

```css
body {
  background: #eee;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: #ddd;
  padding: 20px 0;
  margin-top: 30px;
}

table {
  width: 100%;
}

table thead tr {
  background: #555;
  color: #fff;
}

table thead tr td {
  padding-right: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <h3 style="margin:0">Hello!</h3>
    <br />
    <table cellspacing=0>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <td>#</td>
        <td>First Name</td>
        <td>Last Name</td>
        <td>Phone</td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Test</td>
        <td>+1 234 56-7888</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Test</td>
        <td>+1 234 56-7888</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Padding is necessary for the rest of the block, I've attached a screenshot, could you look, please?